# Add Line before Header in csv using Spring batch

Tags: spring-boot, csv, spring-batch

I have to add one Disclaimer Line in a CSV file before the headers using Spring Batch implementation.
For example, below is my expected CSV File:

**Disclaimer-XYZ...**
**Col1 Col2 Col3**
**abc  efg  pqr**

Currently, I am using FlatFileItemWriter and FlatFileHeaderCallBack to create the CSV File along with writing headers and their corresponding values in it.

But I am not able to add a disclaimer and then follow by the Headers as shown above.

Here is a glimpse of my code:

```
stepWriter.setHeaderCallback(new FlatFileHeaderCallback()
    public void writeHeader(Writer writer) throws IOException{`
    writer.write(disclaimer);
    writer.write(“Col1”, “Col2”,”Col3”);
    }
});
```

But with the above code the actual CSV looks like this:

**Disclaimer-XYZ Col1 Col2 Col3**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, `Disclaimer-XYZ` is part of the header to me, so I would keep it simple and update your header callback to something like:

```
stepWriter.setHeaderCallback(new FlatFileHeaderCallback() {
    @Override
    public void writeHeader(Writer writer) throws IOException {
        writer.write("Disclaimer-XYZ");
        writer.write(System.lineSeparator());
        writer.write("Col1 Col2 Col3");
    }
})
```

This should print:

```
Disclaimer-XYZ
Col1 Col2 Col3
...
```